# Plotly Dropdown output chart

Tags: python, plotly, dropdown

I can't seem to figure out the documentation.  Basically I want to create a dropdown menu and each selection outputs a different chart.  Here is an MRE.  plotly.express is imported as px.

```
race = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/ngpsu22/Ed_Debt-vs.-UBI/raw/main/race_debt_ubi')
education = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/ngpsu22/Ed_Debt-vs.-UBI/raw/main/education_debt_ubi')
income = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/ngpsu22/Ed_Debt-vs.-UBI/raw/main/income_debt_ubi')

fig_race = px.bar(race, x='race', y='percent_has_debt', text='percent_has_debt')
fig_education = px.bar(education,  y='percent_has_debt', text='percent_has_debt')
fig_income = px.bar(income,  y='percent_has_debt', text='percent_has_debt')
```

Basically I want to create a dropdown menu of ['race', 'education', 'income'] that outputs the corresponding chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made your data into a graph that you can select in a drop-down with the 'go' in 'plotly'. The default is to show all the values. I modified it with the help of the official [reference](https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/) and [this site](https://www.kaggle.com/jrmistry/plotly-how-to-change-plot-data-using-dropdowns).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

race = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/ngpsu22/Ed_Debt-vs.-UBI/raw/main/race_debt_ubi')
education = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/ngpsu22/Ed_Debt-vs.-UBI/raw/main/education_debt_ubi')
income = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/ngpsu22/Ed_Debt-vs.-UBI/raw/main/income_debt_ubi')

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=race['race'], y=race['percent_has_debt'], name='race'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[0,1,2,3], y=education['percent_has_debt'], name='education'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[0,1,2,3,4,5], y=income['percent_has_debt'], name='income'))

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[go.layout.Updatemenu(
        active=0,
        buttons=list([
            dict(label="None",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{'visible':[False,False,False]},
                       {'title':'AL','showlegend':True}]),
            dict(label="race",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{'visible':[True,False,False]},
                       {'title':'RACE','showlegend':True}]),
            dict(label="education",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{'visible':[False,True,False]},
                       {'title':'EDUCATION','showlegend':True}]),
            dict(label="income",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{'visible':[False,False,True]},
                       {'title':'INCOME','showlegend':True}]),
    ]
))])


fig.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is so great, exactly what I was looking for.  Is there any way to get it to work without the none option?

Comment: You can remove 'dict(label='None'...)` from the button list.

Comment: When I try getting rid of it...the default trace still has all the charts until I click on one of the results then they update correctly from there

Comment: I was wrong.' None' should be 'visible': everything should be False. I'm trying to figure out how to get nothing to appear at load time.

Comment: Yeah I can't figure it out either....appreciate you trying